# how to overlay 2 graphs in a single plot in GNUplot

Tags: gnuplot

I have two files that has the time as x axis and a value. I need to overlay these two on a single plot. Currently i tried it using GNUplot, but struck in the middle. Here is a sample file

```
01:03:05    6

01:03:15    6
```

and another file

```
01:03:55    6

01:04:10    6
```

I need to plot these two files (say x mark and some other symbol for differentiation) in a single plot. I dont know if it is possible to do that in GNUplot. Currently I have created two grids for each file. But I need both in a single plot. Here is what I have written

```
set multiplot layout 1,2    # engage multiplot mode

set xdata time          ## these three lines control how gnuplot

set timefmt '%H:%M:%S'  ## reads and writes time-formatted data.

set format x '%H:%M:%S' ##

set xtics 05           # make time spacing of 2 minutes

plot 'AAA' u 1:2      # plot the first data set 

plot 'BBB' u 1:2      # plot the second data set 

unset multiplot
```

Can anyone familiar with GNUplot or any other tool (working in linux) can help me.

Answer (score 12):

In order to plot multiple lines in a single plot, simply put them in a single plot command like

```
plot 'AAA' u 1:2, 'BBB' u 1:2
```

There are numerous examples out there that give you a good start with gnuplot. [This](https://mathblog.com/getting-started-with-gnuplot/) one for example shows how to plot multiple lines in one plot.

---

The `multiplot` command you are using in your script would also make it possible to have multiple plot windows like shown [here](http://t16web.lanl.gov/Kawano/gnuplot/plot3-e.html).  You can adjust the position of each subplot by:

```
set size XSIZE,YSIZE        #see `help set size` 
set origin XORIGIN,YORIGIN  #see `help set origin`
```

or (if you have gnuplot 4.2 or newer):

```
set lmargin at screen XMIN  #see `help margin`
set rmargin at screen XMAX
set tmargin at screen YMAX
set bmargin at screen YMIN
```

Comment: You could point out that the position of each "subplot" can be adjusted by `set origin` and `set size` (or alternatively `set lmargin at screen ...`, `set rmargin at screen ...`, etc.) -- Although, my money would be on the first option here ...

Comment: @mgilson feel free to edit my post^^. I just thought, that Raj was not realy after a `multiplot` in a gnuplot sense...

Comment: I just wanted to point out that the link at http://t16web.lanl.gov/Kawano/gnuplot/plot3-e.html is 403 Forbidden